# Automated iTunes tagging?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, applications

I'm looking for an app that alows me to quickly update tags from imported media in iTunes. Something like [itunify](http://www.satsumac.com/iTunify.php) used to when it was free.

Nothing that automagically analyses the music and downloads all lyrics. Just a tool that makes it easy for me to e.g. 'remove n characters from left' or 'switch title - author' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/). Simply download the scripts and put them in:

```
~/Library/iTunes/Scripts
```

Note: You'll likely have to create the folder. From there, you'll see the scripts pop in the iTunes menu.

[image]

His scripts cover everything from modifying play count to find and replace specific words in a song's given field.